# solana rpc get_program_accounts_with_config return Tokenkeg... excluded from account secondary indexes

Tags: rust, solana, solana-program-library

#### curl versions working fine

```bash
curl http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 165
          },
          {
            "memcmp": {
              "offset": 32,
              "bytes": "vines1vzrYbzLMRdu58ou5XTby4qAqVRLmqo36NKPTg"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

#### Rust version failed

> Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "poc"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
solana-client = "1.10.19"
solana-sdk = "1.10.19"
spl-token = "3.3.0"
```

> main.rs

```rust
use solana_client::{
    rpc_client::RpcClient, 
    rpc_filter::{RpcFilterType, Memcmp, MemcmpEncodedBytes, MemcmpEncoding},
    rpc_config::RpcProgramAccountsConfig,
};
use solana_sdk::{commitment_config::CommitmentConfig, bs58};
use spl_token;

fn main() {
    const MY_WALLET_ADDRESS: &str = "vines1vzrYbzLMRdu58ou5XTby4qAqVRLmqo36NKPTg";

    let rpc_url = String::from("http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
    let connection = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(rpc_url, CommitmentConfig::confirmed());

    let filters = Some(vec![
        RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp {
            offset: 32,
            bytes: MemcmpEncodedBytes::Base58(
                bs58::encode(MY_WALLET_ADDRESS).into_string(),
            ),
            encoding: Some(MemcmpEncoding::Binary),
        }),
        RpcFilterType::DataSize(165),
    ]);

    let accounts = connection.get_program_accounts_with_config(
        &spl_token::ID,
        RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
            filters,
            ..RpcProgramAccountsConfig::default()
        },
    ).unwrap();

    println!("Found {:?} token account(s) for wallet {MY_WALLET_ADDRESS}: ", accounts.len());

    for (i, account) in accounts.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("-- Token Account Address {:?}:  {:?} --", i, account);
    }
}
```

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ClientError { request: Some(GetProgramAccounts), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32010, message: "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key", data: Empty }) }', src/main.rs:32:7

This look identical to me, not sure what causing this. I did read through discord and github which said provider remove `Tokenkeg...` support due to high resource used but incase `curl` is working fine so I don't think that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

What i miss is `account_config`, so here's a working answer to my own question.

```ini
[package]
name = "poc"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
solana-account-decoder = "1.10.20"
solana-client = "1.10.19"
solana-sdk = "1.10.19"
spl-token = "3.3.0"
```

```rust
use solana_client::{
    rpc_client::RpcClient, 
    rpc_filter::{RpcFilterType, Memcmp, MemcmpEncodedBytes, MemcmpEncoding},
    rpc_config::{RpcProgramAccountsConfig, RpcAccountInfoConfig},
};
use solana_sdk::{commitment_config::CommitmentConfig};
use spl_token;
use solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding;

fn main() {
    const MY_WALLET_ADDRESS: &str = "vines1vzrYbzLMRdu58ou5XTby4qAqVRLmqo36NKPTg";

    let rpc_url = String::from("http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");

    let connection = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(rpc_url, CommitmentConfig::confirmed());

    let filters = Some(vec![
        RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp {
            offset: 32,
            bytes: MemcmpEncodedBytes::Base58(MY_WALLET_ADDRESS.to_string()),
            encoding: Some(MemcmpEncoding::Binary),
        }),
        RpcFilterType::DataSize(165),
    ]);

    let accounts = connection.get_program_accounts_with_config(
        &spl_token::ID,
        RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
            filters,
            account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
                encoding: Some(UiAccountEncoding::Base64),
                commitment: Some(connection.commitment()),
                ..RpcAccountInfoConfig::default()
            },
            ..RpcProgramAccountsConfig::default()
        },
    ).unwrap();

    println!("Found {:?} token account(s) for wallet {MY_WALLET_ADDRESS}: ", accounts.len());

    for (i, account) in accounts.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("-- Token Account Address {:?}:  {:?} --", i, account);
    }
}
```